# NoneType' object has no attribute 'text

Tags: python, pyqt5

I can't solve this problem, i've tried many suggested solutions but nothing.
To be short. A table withe editable cells. When I click the button to read the modified cell I get

> File "...", line 703, in calendar_cell
> self.cell.append(table.item(row, 0).text())
>
> AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'text'

This is the involved script

```
def Open_tab(self, refresh=False):

        self.year = strftime("%Y")
        self.month = strftime("%-m")
        self.new_month = Functions.convert_number_month[self.month]
        cart = calendar.monthrange(int(self.year), int(self.month))[1]
        self.currentId = None
        self.Cal_label.setText(self.item)
        if self.Main_tabWidget.currentIndex() != 0 or refresh:
            self.Main_tabWidget.setCurrentIndex(0)
            year = self.year
            month = self.month
            self.fill_Table(self.Calendar_table, year, month)


def fill_Table(self, table: QTableWidget, year, month, editable=True):
    [...]
    cursor.execute(query)
    results = cursor.fetchall()
    self.nbrrows = int(cursor.rowcount)
   
    for data, row in enumerate(results):
        trn = 0
        [...]
        while ii <= cart
            [...]
            if not editable:
                    cell.setFlags(Qt.ItemIsSelectable | Qt.ItemIsEnabled)
            
            ii = ii + 1
    self.year1 = year
    self.mese1 = month
    
    self.Cal_btn.clicked.connect(self.read_cal_cell)

def read_cal_cell(self):
    self.calendar_cell(self.Calendar_table, self.year1, self.mese1)

def calendar_cell(self, table: QTableWidget, year, month):
   
    self.just_one = 0
    self.cell = []
    for row in range(self.nbrrows):
        self.cell.append(table.item(row, 0).text())
```

I use this piece of code in another script and I can read the modified cells, the useful code is the same but...

Comment: You may have to know why the call to `table.item` is returning None. If your question is why it is returning None, you should give more detail like the sample data, how the code is used etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add a `None` check:

```
def calendar_cell(self, table: QTableWidget, year, month):
   
    self.just_one = 0
    self.cell = []
    for row in range(self.nbrrows):
        item = table.item(row, 0)
        if item:
            self.cell.append(item.text())
```

If you are using Python 3.9 you can assign directly in the if statement with the walrus (`:=`) operator:

```
        if item := table.item(row, 0):
            self.cell.append(item.text())
```

The error is clear:

```
File "...", line 703, in calendar_cell self.cell.append(table.item(row, 0).text())

AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'text'
```

For some reason the call `table.item(row, 0)` is returning `None`, and `None` has no `text` method which in Python gives `AttributeError`.

Comment: You are correct. I made deep code checks and found that `table.item(row, 0)` is None. I changed the walues of rows and columns and it works as expected

Comment: QTableWidget returns `None` for items in which no QTableWidgetItem has been explicitly set or has not been manually modified: if you only set the row and column count and no QTableWidgetItem is set, `item()` will always return None even for valid indexes.